# Authenticate and load private Esri vector tile service to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, vector-tiles, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm trying to load the following ArcGIS Vector Tile Service into QGIS.

https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/GB_MasterMap_VML_BASE_v1/VectorTileServer

I already have an authentication configuration set up using OAuth as per the guide here:

https://north-road.com/2022/09/16/securely-accessing-arcgis-online-agol-and-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis-2022-update/

This allows connection to our AGOL organisation via the 'ArcGIS REST Server' option, but using this configuration for the vector tile service fails.

I'm not sure if I need to append an API key or token to the service or style URL and if so, what this URL would look like?

Current settings are as follows:

[image]